# Examples of False-Discovery Rates Being Used Outside Of Biology

Tags: false-discovery-rate

I feel like the go-to motivation behind FDR is microarrays. I would like to know of applications that use FDRs that are not biostatistics related.

Comment: FDR can be used in any multiple comparisons situation. Microarrays, GWAS and the like are an obvious and visible use case for FDR because of the extremely large number of predictors entailed in using genetic information to make guesses about some outcome.

Comment: "FDR can be used in any multiple comparisons situation". Do you have links to papers showing examples of this?

Comment: If you [search Google Scholar for "false discovery rate" and "sociology"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&num=100&ie=UTF-8&q=%22false+discovery+rate%22+%22sociology%22), or ["false discovery rate" and "epidemiology" -genetic -genomic](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&num=100&ie=UTF-8&q=%22false+discovery+rate%22+and+%22epidemiology%22+-genetic+-genomic), or you get the pattern, you can find thousands of papers doing so.